# Canonicity of Čech cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology, cech-cohomology

For a topological space $X$, consider the Leray covering $U_\lambda$ (i.e. $\cap U_\lambda$ is sufficiently fine, e.g. affine for Zariski topology) of $X$.

For a sheaf $F$ on $X,$ the cohomology $H^i(X,F)$ is calculated via Čech cohomology. However, to calculate Čech cohomology, we need to number each $U_\lambda$ once for all.

### Q. Is there a canonical (or natural) isomorphism between Čech cohomologies defined by different numberings ?

If $\lambda$ consists of two elements, there is a natural identification, but for general numberings, I got lost and don’t know where to go.

Please help me to know what happens for general indices and numberings.

Comment: Ch. II, Theorem 5.7.1 (and Theorem 4.7.2) in the book "Topologie algebrique et theorie des faisceaux" by Godement, and section 3.8 in Grothendieck's Tohoku paper (i.e., "Sur quelques points d'algebre homologique").